# angular 8 code problem change date format

Tags: angular, angular8

I have a code fragment:

```
<div
          class="table-row-wraper"
          *ngFor="let user of users; let i = index"
          id="{{ user.id }}"
        >
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="channel">
            <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'bla'">
              <ng-container [ngSwitch]="user.role">
                <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'user'">
                  <user-service-item
                    [user]="users[i]"
                    [channel]="'userRole'"
                  ></user-service-item>
                </ng-container>
</div>
```

and  I want change date from all items in YYYY-mm-dd to yyyy-mm-dd HH:ii.
Please help me.

Comment: Where is the date in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pipe for changing the date format as per your requirement.
So wherever you show the date use this pipe alongwith to change the format.

For example:

```
{{myDate | myDateFormat: 'D_T_FMT'}}
```

your Pipe should be having the following line of codes:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'myDateFormat'
})
export class MyDateFormat extends DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: string): any {
        let formatter;
        switch (args) {
            case 'D_FMT':
                {
                    formatter = super.transform(value, DC.D_FMT);
                    break;
                }
            case 'D_T_FMT':
                {
                    formatter = super.transform(value, DC.D_T_FMT);
                    break;
                }
               
            default:
                {
                    formatter = super.transform(value, 'dd/mm');
                    break;
                }
        }
        return formatter;
    }
}

export class DC {
  static readonly D_FMT = 'MM/dd/yy';
  static readonly D_T_FMT = `${DC.D_FMT} hh:mm aa`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Angular Pipes**

```
{{ date_value | date :'short'}}
```

**Expected Output Format**

```
  6/30/20, 5:24 AM
```

Angular Date Pipe documentation [reference](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

May be this article would be  [helpful](https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/angular-date-pipe-formatting-date-times-in-angular-with-examples/)

**Using Ant Design**

But from your previous comments it looks like you are not interested in `Angular Pipes` then I would suggest a `front-end library` that can do the job for you if you don't have any constraints using them names `antd`.
You can achieve it in this way

**HTML**

```
 <nz-date-picker [nzFormat]="dateFormat" formControlName="Date"></nz-date-picker>
```

**Typescript**

```
dateFormat: "yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss";
```

**Using Format Date**

```
let formattedDt = formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZZZZZ', 'en_US');
//Change it as per your need
```